# Adding characters to String

Tags: java

I'm doings some beginners task in JAVA. With the help of FOR I'm going to create two simple triangles by just adding simple characters like * to a string like this:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

and

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

I have done the first triangle with the code below, perhaps it could be done in some simplier/smarter way? But I'm not sure how to create the other triangle that starts with five * ?

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

String word = "";

        for (int x=1; x<5+1; x++){
        word += "*";

        System.out.println(word);

        }
}
}
```

Comment: How does your question title relate to your question body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the whole stuff without actually using `String` variables. Use one loop for every row and a nested loop for the number of asterisks in the current row. When you are at `current` row you have `6 - current` asterisks. Sample code follows:

```
for (int row = 1; row <= 5; row++) {
   for (int i = 1; i <= 6 - row; i++) {
       System.out.print("*");
   }

   System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: @Oli - This site is for questions and answers. The OP showed some effort and I helped him. The question is not a `gimme teh codez` type. I think you are getting it too serious...

Comment: That's fair.  But your answer would be better served by including some explanation.  (I would remove the -1, but I can't until you edit your question again!)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "decrementing" loop counter like this:

```
for (int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
    // Do something
}
```

Inside the loop, you could use another loop to create a string of `i` stars, and then print it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the same string `word`, and ask for the [substring(int,int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29). Remember to collect the return value to the old string itself. You need to a loop that runs until the length of string is **0**.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use the substring method to print part of a longer string:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String stars = "*****";

        for (int x=4; x>=0; x--){

             System.out.println(stars.substring(x));

        }
    }
}
```